# ContextMenu with custom listview items in a fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, contextmenu

i've been trying to implement a contextMenu in my listView for a while. When i click a item, nothing seens to happen. I read some answers from another posts, but i wasn't successefull on the implementation, if someone could help me, i'll be gratefull.

**My fragment:**

```
public class GroupMembersFragment extends Fragment {
private int positionClicked;
private ListView memberList;
private User loggedUser;
private static final int EXCLUIR = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_group_members, container, false);

        UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO(getContext());
        loggedUser = userDAO.getLoggedUser();
        userDAO.close();

        memberList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.members_list);

        Call<GroupMembersSync> call = new RetrofitInitializator().getGroupService().getGroupMembers(loggedUser);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<GroupMembersSync>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GroupMembersSync> call, Response<GroupMembersSync> response) {
                List<User> users = getUsers(response);

                setAdapterGroupMembers(users);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GroupMembersSync> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Group members error", t.getMessage());
            }
        });

        memberList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                positionClicked = i;

                return false;
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        registerForContextMenu(memberList);
    }

    private List<User> getUsers(Response<GroupMembersSync> response) {
        GroupMembersSync groupMembersSync = response.body();
        return getUsersFromSync(groupMembersSync);
    }

    private void setAdapterGroupMembers(List<User> users) {
        GroupMembersAdapter groupMembersAdapter = new GroupMembersAdapter(getContext(), users);
        memberList.setAdapter(groupMembersAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        /*AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;*/
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        /*final User user = (User) memberList.getItemAtPosition(info.position);*/

        /*MenuItem menuExcluir = */menu.add(Menu.NONE, EXCLUIR, menu.NONE, "Excluir do grupo");

        /*menuExcluir.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                Call<GroupMembersSync> call = new RetrofitInitializator().getGroupService().excludeMember(user, loggedUser.getUserKey());
                call.enqueue(new Callback<GroupMembersSync>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<GroupMembersSync> call, Response<GroupMembersSync> response) {
                        List<User> users = getUsers(response);

                        setAdapterGroupMembers(users);
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Usuário excluido do grupo com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<GroupMembersSync> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Erro ao excluir o usuário do grupo, por favor tentar novamente.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("on delete error", t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case EXCLUIR:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sucesso!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    public List<User> getUsersFromSync(GroupMembersSync groupMembersSync) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<User> users = null;

        try {
            ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(new TypeReference<List<User>>() {
            });

            users = reader.readValue(groupMembersSync.getUsers());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return users;
    }
}
```

**The adapter:**

```
public class GroupMembersAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<User> users;

    public GroupMembersAdapter(Context context, List<User> users) {
        this.context = context;
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return users.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return users.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Utils utils = new Utils();
        LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        View listView = null;
        User user = users.get(i);

        try {
            listView = view;


            if (listView == null)
            {
                inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                listView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_member_list, viewGroup, false);
            }

            TextView nameField = listView.findViewById(R.id.members_completeName);
            nameField.setText(user.getUserCompleteName());

            TextView dateField = listView.findViewById(R.id.members_joinDate);
            dateField.setText(utils.formatStringToLocalData(user.getSignInDate()));

            /*ImageView profilePicField = listView.findViewById(R.id.members_profilePicture);
            profilePicField.setText(feed.getText());*/

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listView;
    }
}
```

**The listView:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.breno.teste.GroupMembersFragment">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/members_list"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**And the itens layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/person"
            android:id="@+id/members_profilePicture"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/members_completeName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/members_joinDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try removing `setOnItemLongClickListener` call - that might interfere with the callback. Also, have you debugged this? Is your on create context menu being called?

Comment: The setOnItemLongClickListener was a test and the onCreateContextMenu is not being called. @dominicoder

Comment: I don't see anything clearly wrong. I'd step through `registerForContextMenu` and open up the source code and put a breakpoint in `View.createContextMenu` - this is what delegates to your `onCreateContextMenu` implementation, to see what that's doing.

Comment: I'll try to find out again, but thanks for the help!